# Find nearest smaller number

Tags: r, vector, numeric

I have a vector of numbers

```
f <- c(1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 19, 27)
```

I want to compare the values in the vector to another number, and find the closest *smaller* value.

For example, if the input number is 18, then the closest, smaller value in the vector is 12 (position 6 in the vector).
If the input is 19, then the result should be the value 19, i.e. the index 7.

Answer (score 15):

I think this answer is pretty straightforward:

```
f <- c(1,3,6,8,10,12,19,27)
x <- 18

# find the value that is closest to x
maxless <- max(f[f <= x])
# find out which value that is
which(f == maxless)
```

Comment: the last two lines can be written in one line: which.max(f[f<=x])

Comment: @nigelhenry your code will only work when 'f' is sorted and ascending (which it is in the example), since you are giving the index of the element in the truncated vector.

Comment: @le_andrew - you're right. OK

Answer (score 8):

If your vector `f` is always sorted, then you can do `sum(f <= x)`

```
f <- c(1,3,6,8,10,12,19,27)

x <- 18
sum(f <= x)
# [1] 6

x <- 19
sum(f <= x)
# [1] 7
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this (not a perfect solution)

```
x<-c(1,3,6,8,10,12,19,27)
showIndex<-function(x,input){
 abs.diff<-abs(x-input)
 index.value<-unique(ifelse(abs.diff==0,which.min(abs.diff),which.min(abs.diff)-1))
return(index.value)
 }
 showIndex(x,12)
    [1] 6
showIndex(x,19)
[1] 7
```

Comment: the problem is that if the inout is 19...then the output would need to be 7 (the index)...

Comment: `which.min(abs(x-18))` gives you the index. I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: x[which.min(abs(x-19))-1]
[1] 18....that is the problem because if the inpout is 19 then it mataches directly the value and there should be no subtraction of 1

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
x <- 18
f <- c(1,3,6,8,10,12,19,27)

ifelse(x %in% f, which(f %in% x), which.min(abs(f - x)) - 1)
```

That way if `x` is not in `f`, it will return the nearest previous index. If `x` is in `f`, it will return `x` index.

Comment: Beaupre  how would I make sure that if I search ftr the nearest value of 19, the thing returns 7 (the index of 19) not 6 (the index of 12)...because of the input is exactly a position in the vector it would need to show that...

Answer (score 2):

Another one:

```
which.min(abs(18 - replace(f, f>18, Inf)))
#[1] 6

f[which.min(abs(18 - replace(f, f>18, Inf)))]
#[1] 12
```

Or as a function:

```
minsmaller <- function(x,value) which.min(abs(value - replace(x, x>value, Inf)))
minsmaller(f, 18)
#[1] 6
minsmaller(f, 19)
#[1] 7
```

Answer (score 0):

In a functional programming style:

```
f <- c(1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 12, 19, 27)
x <- 18
Position(function(fi) fi <= x, f, right = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `findInterval`:

```
findInterval(18:19, f)
#[1] 6 7
```

And building a more concrete function:

```
ff = function(x, table)
{
    ot = order(table)
    ans = findInterval(x, table[ot]) 
    ot[ifelse(ans == 0, NA, ans)]
}

set.seed(007); sf = sample(f)
sf
#[1] 27  6  1 12 10 19  8  3
ff(c(0, 1, 18, 19, 28), sf)
#[1] NA  3  4  6  1
```