# R - Obtain the closest smaller and bigger values compared to a reference value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, closest

Is there an elegant way to obtain the closest smaller and bigger values compared to some reference value? Following example should clarify my goal:

```
set.seed(42)

df_Date <- data.frame(Date = seq(lubridate::date('2022-01-01'), lubridate::date('2022-01-20'), by = 2))
df_Dummy <- data.frame(Dummy = seq(-0.2, 0.2, by = 0.05)) 
my_df <- df_Date |>
  dplyr::full_join(df_Dummy, by = character()) |>
  dplyr::mutate(Value = rnorm(90)) |>
  dplyr::mutate(given_date = lubridate::date('2022-01-10'),
                given_Dummy = 0.17)
```

I want to obtain the rows, where `Date` is closest to `given_date` and `Dummy` is closest to `given_dummy`. For each case, I want the closest smaller AND bigger value, since I would like to interpolate in the end.

Right now I am achieving the desired result the following way:

```
temp <- my_df |>
  dplyr::mutate(Diff_Date = difftime(given_date, Date, units = 'days'))

temp.pos <- temp |> 
  dplyr::filter(Diff_Date >= 0) |> 
  dplyr::filter(Diff_Date == min(Diff_Date)) 

temp.neg <- temp |> 
  dplyr::filter(Diff_Date <= 0) |> 
  dplyr::filter(Diff_Date == max(Diff_Date)) 

temp2 <- dplyr::bind_rows(temp.neg, temp.pos) |>
  dplyr::distinct(.keep_all = TRUE) |>
  dplyr::mutate(Diff_Dummy = Dummy - given_Dummy)

temp2.pos <- temp2 |> 
  dplyr::filter(Diff_Dummy >= 0) |> 
  dplyr::filter(Diff_Dummy == min(Diff_Dummy)) 

temp2.neg <- temp2 |> 
  dplyr::filter(Diff_Dummy <= 0) |> 
  dplyr::filter(Diff_Dummy == max(Diff_Dummy)) 

final_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(temp2.neg, temp2.pos) |>
  dplyr::distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
```

Desired output:

```
> final_df
        Date Dummy      Value given_date given_Dummy Diff_Date Diff_Dummy
1 2022-01-11  0.15  1.5757275 2022-01-10        0.17   -1 days      -0.02
2 2022-01-09  0.15 -0.7267048 2022-01-10        0.17    1 days      -0.02
3 2022-01-11  0.20  0.6428993 2022-01-10        0.17   -1 days       0.03
4 2022-01-09  0.20 -1.3682810 2022-01-10        0.17    1 days       0.03
```

Note that if there is an exact match between `Dummy` and `given_dummy` resp. `Date` and `given_date`, i.e. `Diff_Date == 0` resp. `Diff_Dummy == 0`, then only this row is wanted.

I would like a more concise code, maybe using `dplyr`, which is easier to grasp and provides the same result. I came across the following threads, but I wasn't able to come up with a solution:

[Find nearest smaller number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314007/find-nearest-smaller-number)

[r-find two closest values in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446042/r-find-two-closest-values-in-a-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the differences of the two columns, then use `filter` to get your desired rows. We use `min` when the difference is larger than 0 and use `max` when the difference is smaller than 0.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_df %>% 
  mutate(Diff_date = Date - given_date,
         Diff_dummy = Dummy - given_Dummy) %>% 
  filter((Diff_date == min(Diff_date[Diff_date > 0]) | 
            Diff_date == max(Diff_date[Diff_date < 0])) &
           (Diff_dummy == min(Diff_dummy[Diff_dummy > 0]) | 
              Diff_dummy == max(Diff_dummy[Diff_dummy < 0])))

        Date Dummy      Value given_date given_Dummy Diff_date Diff_dummy
1 2022-01-09  0.15 -0.7267048 2022-01-10        0.17   -1 days      -0.02
2 2022-01-09  0.20 -1.3682810 2022-01-10        0.17   -1 days       0.03
3 2022-01-11  0.15  1.5757275 2022-01-10        0.17    1 days      -0.02
4 2022-01-11  0.20  0.6428993 2022-01-10        0.17    1 days       0.03
```

#### Data

```
my_df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18995, 18995, 18995, 18995, 
18995, 18995, 18995, 18995, 18995, 18997, 18997, 18997, 18997, 
18997, 18997, 18997, 18997, 18997, 18999, 18999, 18999, 18999, 
18999, 18999, 18999, 18999, 18999, 19001, 19001, 19001, 19001, 
19001, 19001, 19001, 19001, 19001, 19003, 19003, 19003, 19003, 
19003, 19003, 19003, 19003, 19003, 19005, 19005, 19005, 19005, 
19005, 19005, 19005, 19005, 19005, 19007, 19007, 19007, 19007, 
19007, 19007, 19007, 19007, 19007, 19009, 19009, 19009, 19009, 
19009, 19009, 19009, 19009, 19009, 19011, 19011, 19011, 19011, 
19011, 19011, 19011, 19011, 19011), class = "Date"), Dummy = c(-0.2, 
-0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, 
-0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0, 
0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 
0.15, 0.2, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 
-0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, -0.2, -0.15, 
-0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 
0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 
0.15, 0.2, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2), 
    Value = c(1.37095844714667, -0.564698171396089, 0.363128411337339, 
    0.63286260496104, 0.404268323140999, -0.106124516091484, 
    1.51152199743894, -0.0946590384130976, 2.01842371387704, 
    -0.062714099052421, 1.30486965422349, 2.28664539270111, -1.38886070111234, 
    -0.278788766817371, -0.133321336393658, 0.635950398070074, 
    -0.284252921416072, -2.65645542090478, -2.44046692857552, 
    1.32011334573019, -0.306638594078475, -1.78130843398, -0.171917355759621, 
    1.2146746991726, 1.89519346126497, -0.4304691316062, -0.25726938276893, 
    -1.76316308519478, 0.460097354831271, -0.639994875960119, 
    0.455450123241219, 0.704837337228819, 1.03510352196992, -0.608926375407211, 
    0.50495512329797, -1.71700867907334, -0.784459008379496, 
    -0.850907594176518, -2.41420764994663, 0.0361226068922556, 
    0.205998600200254, -0.361057298548666, 0.758163235699517, 
    -0.726704827076575, -1.36828104441929, 0.432818025888717, 
    -0.811393176186672, 1.44410126172125, -0.431446202613345, 
    0.655647883402207, 0.321925265203947, -0.783838940880375, 
    1.57572751979198, 0.642899305717316, 0.0897606465996057, 
    0.276550747291463, 0.679288816055271, 0.0898328865790817, 
    -2.99309008315293, 0.284882953530659, -0.367234642740975, 
    0.185230564865609, 0.581823727365507, 1.39973682729268, -0.727292059474465, 
    1.30254263204414, 0.335848119752074, 1.03850609869762, 0.920728568290646, 
    0.720878162866862, -1.04311893856785, -0.0901863866107067, 
    0.623518161999544, -0.953523357772344, -0.542828814573857, 
    0.580996497681682, 0.768178737834591, 0.463767588540167, 
    -0.885776297409679, -1.09978089864786, 1.51270700980493, 
    0.257921437532031, 0.0884402291595864, -0.120896537539089, 
    -1.19432889516053, 0.611996898040387, -0.217139845746521, 
    -0.182756706331922, 0.93334632857116, 0.821773110508249), 
    given_date = structure(c(19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 
    19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 
    19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 
    19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 
    19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 
    19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 
    19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 
    19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 
    19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 
    19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 19002, 
    19002, 19002, 19002, 19002), class = "Date"), given_Dummy = c(0.17, 
    0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
    0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
    0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
    0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
    0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
    0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
    0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
    0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 
    0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-90L))
```

Comment: May I ask why a "[]" is needed for the "Diff_date" column? Why can't you filter directly on "min(Diff_date > 0)" but need that extra bracket instead?

Comment: @SeanM Because the code is trying to get positive `min` and negative `max` values